# Structuring Docker Compose for larger Django backends

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, celery

I'm currently trying to set up my backend with Docker Compose. I successfully managed to integrate my PostgreSQL database, my Django backend service as well as RabbitMQ message broker with each other.

What I'm trying to achieve is setting up Celery workers, Celery beat and Celery Flower in separate Docker containers so my Django backend can work with them.

The problem: My Celery tasks need to access Django's models and the database. Therefore, I need to copy some backend files into the Celery containers as well. I just don't feel like it's the best way to do that. I need to copy my entire backend, containing my tasks, routines, models, urls and views to get my Celery workers to actually run. What would be the best workflow to realize that?